# Renderer property changed explanation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

What does it mean when `Renderer` property is changed in renderer class (`OnElementPropertyChanged` is called with `e.PropertyName == 'Renderer'`)? Does each view contain reference to its renderer?